# Do we have super Plucker relations for a super Grassmannian?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, cluster-algebras

Super Grassmannians are introduced by Manin, see [for example](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227218661_On_the_rigidity_of_super-Grassmannians). We have [Plucker relation](https://www.academia.edu/5178360/PLUCKER_EMBDDING_OF_GRASSMANNIAN_AND_A_TOY_EXAMPLE_OF_CLUSTER_ALGEBRA) for Grassmannian.

Are there some references about super Plucker relations for super Grassmannian? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [The quantum chiral Minkowski and conformal superspaces](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.atmp/1337951930) by Cervantes, Fioresi, and Lledó the super Grassmannian of $(2|0)$ planes in $\mathbb{C}^{4|1}$ is considered. In Equation (4.9) some "super Plücker relations" are given for this particular super Grassmannian. The relations contain the classical Plücker relation for $Gr(2,4)$ plus some more relations.

Answer (score 3):

There's a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.12011) titled *On super Plücker embedding and possible application to cluster algebras* just came out this summer.